# How can I delete the first n lines in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

How can I delete the first *n* lines in a string?

Example:

```
String str = @"a
b
c
d
e";

String output = DeleteLines(str, 2)
//Output is "c
//d
//e"
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use LINQ:

```
String str = @"a
b
c
d
e";

int n = 2;
string[] lines = str
    .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    .Skip(n)
    .ToArray();

string output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);

// Output is 
// "c
// d
// e"
```

Comment: beat me to it, but you need `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` since Split interprets \r and \n separately

Comment: @Marlon - I'm not sure if removing empty entries was a requirement in the question. I figured it wasn't since the question focused on lines and not characters/words.

Comment: you chickened out of getting it all in one unreadable line? Call that a proper use of LINQ? ;)

Answer (score 16):

If you need to take into account "\r\n" and "\r" and "\n" it's better to use the following regex:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveFirstLines(string text, int linesCount)
    {
        var lines = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n").Skip(linesCount);
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508203/best-way-to-split-string-into-lines) are some more details about splitting text into lines.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
public static string DeleteLines(string s, int linesToRemove)
{
    return s.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), 
                   linesToRemove + 1
        ).Skip(linesToRemove)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

the next example:

```
string str = @"a
b
c
d
e";
string output = DeleteLines(str, 2);
```

returns

```
c
d
e
```

Comment: If the content has empty lines it returns the wrong result as they're removed

Answer (score 3):

Combination of [Get the index of the nth occurrence of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/c-indexof-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string) (search for Environment.NewLine) and substring should do the trick.

Comment: Could you paste the relevant bits of the answer you mention into your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static string DeleteLines (string text, int lineCount) {
    while (text.Split('\n').Length > lineCount)
        text = text.Remove(0, text.Split('\n')[0].Length + 1);
    return text;
}
```

It might not be very efficient but it works perfectly for the little project i've been working on recently

Comment: You should not use splitting like this in any project, declare it as a variable and reuse it.
It's a very bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    private static string DeleteLines(string input, int lines)
    {
        var result = input;
        for(var i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        {
            var idx = result.IndexOf('\n');
            if (idx < 0)
            {
                // do what you want when there are less than the required lines
                return string.Empty;
            }
            result = result.Substring(idx+1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Note: This method is not ideal for extremely long multi-line strings as it does not consider memory management. If dealing with these kind of strings, I suggest you alter the method to use the StringBuilder class.

Comment: Why not just find the nth `\n` and do a single substring from that point onwards. So many of the above answers are really inefficient I was expecting this one to do it the simple way. I see that was @Lukáš Novotný's answer (he referenced, but did not repeat here).

Answer (score 0):

With ability to delete **first n** lines or **last n** lines:

```
public static string DeleteLines(
     string stringToRemoveLinesFrom, 
     int numberOfLinesToRemove, 
     bool startFromBottom = false) {
            string toReturn = "";
            string[] allLines = stringToRemoveLinesFrom.Split(
                    separator: Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
                    options: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (startFromBottom)
                toReturn = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allLines.Take(allLines.Length - numberOfLinesToRemove));
            else
                toReturn = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allLines.Skip(numberOfLinesToRemove));
            return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string DeleteLines(string input, int linesToSkip)
{
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < linesToSkip; ++i)
        startIndex = input.IndexOf('\n', startIndex) + 1;
    return input.Substring(startIndex);
}
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers (especially since this is an old question that already has several other high-quality answers).