# C# - Split string by lines?

Tags: c#

Let's say, for example, I have the following string downloaded from a .txt file in the web.

```
line1
line2
line3
```

How can I split the whole string by lines, so I can use splitted[0] to get line1, splitted[1] to get line 2, etc..? Thanks!

Can I use?

```
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(input, @"\r?\n|\r");
```

Thanks

Comment: `Can I use?` Why don't you try?

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` might also be worth a try: `string.Split(Environment.NewLine);`

Answer (score 11):

Use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) to get the `string[]` with all lines:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string line10 = allLines[9]; // exception if there are less
string line100 = allLines.ElementAtOrDefault(99); // null if there are less
```

If you already have a string you can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `Environment.NewLine`

```
string[] textLines = text.Split(new[]{ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. The string I'm getting is 0x0B, for example. When using short.Parse, it fails, it says the input wasn't in correct format. Why's that? If I use 0x0B in VS it works fine, but when I get it from, a text file..

Comment: Additionally, if the file is large, OP can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, i.e. yields lines one by one. That's useful if there is no need to keep all lines in memory at the same time.

Comment: @user2714359: You might want to ask another question then. You're welcome :)

Comment: @user2714359: Don't forget to accept the answer which solves your problem. You haven't accepted any answers for your questions so far.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
var result = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n");
```

as indicated here: [Best way to split string into lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508203/best-way-to-split-string-into-lines)

Comment: First example will create an additional empty string for each newline.

Answer (score 2):

If you are downloading a file, then open it and `ReadAllLines`

```
var f= File.ReadAllLines(filPath)
```

`ReadAllLines` returns `string[]`.