# How can I delete the first line of a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am currently working on a project and I need to delete the first line of a TextBox. How can I delete this first line? It is supposed to delete the line at every loop. I am using a WindowsFormApp in Visual Studio.

Comment: What sort of TextBox? Please tag `WPF`, `WinForms`, `ASP.NET`, etc. to indicate the technology you are working with.

Comment: Can you post your code for this?

Comment: If you want to delete 1 line, why do you need a loop?  Perhaps some code would help us understand.  Certainly [Ask] and the WELCOME [TOUR] would help you understand the site better

Comment: could you post your text also?

Comment: Mr.Cofee already answered my question ahah

Comment: The way this place works is that if someone helped you or you feel that their answer was good, you upvote them.  If you asked a question, and you ended up using one of the answers, you "accept" it.  That way 2 things happen 1) the answerer gets a _"reputation"_ boost, but more importantly, the next person who asks a question like yours gets an indication of which answers were good and answered the question

Comment: The reason why I don't put any lines of code is because I speak french and my lines are in french

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBox1.Lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ctrl.Text = @"First
                2nd
                3rd";

var lines = multiline.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
ctrl.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.Skip(1));
```

For more details on how to split the text into lines please see
[Best way to split string into lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508203/best-way-to-split-string-into-lines) .

Answer (score 0):

For a plain old Windows Forms multiline text box, this works:

```
 var wasText = textBox1.Text;
 var lineEndIndex = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
 if (lineEndIndex >= 0) {
     textBox1.Text = wasText.Substring(lineEndIndex + Environment.NewLine.Length);
 }
```